# Problems with finding network path in Windows Batch Script Windows XP to a terminal with Embedded XP

Tags: batch-file

I am almost done developing a batch file to delete files from a specific directory via remote commands. The only remaining problem to solve is getting the path name corret. The computer I am using is Windows XP, and I am logging into a machine with embedded XP.

I first use NET USE to connect to the terminal:

```
NET USE \\%IP% /user:UFDOMAIN\luci "city!!"
```

where UFDOMAIN is the Domain, luci is the user and city!! is the password (not actual domain, user, and password, but close enough).

After successfully connecting, I am temporarily trying to use the COPY command to prove I can do it before I start deleting like mad.

```
COPY \\%IP%\Tools\Support\filetodelete.html filetodeletecopy.html
```

However, when I run the code, I get an error:

> The network path was not found.

I have tried multiple ways, including

```
\\%IP%\C:\Tools\Support\filetodelete.html
\\10.xx.x.x\Tools\Support\filetodelete.html REM - 10.xx.x.x is the actual IP
\\%IP%C:\Tools\Support\filetodelete.html
```

None of these work, of course (I didn't think they would, either, but it is easier to get the simple possiblities out of the way), and this code is based off of code that already works with other terminals. I thought it might be the terminal, but for all intensive purposes, this terminal is just like the others, only containing different files.

Comment: Have you tried \\%IP%\C$\Path\File.ext?  The C$ is the default Windows share to the C: drive...  If that doesn't work, you'll have to create a share on the remote machine and access the share via \\%IP%\ShareName\Path\File.ext...

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It was exactly what was needed, thank you so much!

Comment: I'll convert my comment into an answer then -- so you can mark it correct, which will change the question to an answered question so others won't open it just to find that it has already been answered...

Answer (score 0):

Windows creates default shares using a special syntax.  Instead of using `C:`, you have to use `C$` like this:

```
del \\%IP%\C$\Path\File.ext
```

If Windows is configured to disable the `C$` type of shares, then you will have to create an explicit share to the area of the hard drive that you want to share by browsing to that folder in Windows Explorer, right clicking the folder, selecting Properties and Sharing.  From there you can create a share to give access to that folder and all of its contents via the share name.  For instance, I could create a share for the C: drive called `CDrive`, then access it this way:

```
del \\%IP%\CDrive\Path\File.ext
```

You should use caution when creating explicit shares though since by default *Read* access is granted to *Everyone*.  You can adjust this, but you should be careful...